# How can I ensure that my variable is not available directly outside the angular factory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I have an angular factory which includes methods to manage a list of objects. One of those methods helps to make an ajax call and load more items into the list. When that method is called, I have a need to show the "in progress" state of the ajax call (i.e. loading of items). Now, I can just use a simple variable like `service.isLoading = ...` and set it to `true` or `false` depending on the state. However, the problem is that this variable becomes visible to the outside and any controllers that use this factory.

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .factory('appFactory', function QuestionsServ(...) {

        var service = {
            list: []
        };


        // loading state to help show if system is busy loading ajax data
        service.isBusy = false;


        service.loadItems = function () {
            service.isBusy = true;

            // make ajax call here
            var request = ...

            return request.then( function(res) {
                 // after successful loading show state is not busy
                 service.isBusy = false;
                 ...
            }

        ...
```

But I would like to be able to keep this variable visible within the factory only. So I can change `isBusy` to something similar to the following.

```
        service.isBusy = function () {
            return false;
        }
```

But now it is apparently busy from the factory as well. I am no longer able to access `isBusy` from within `loadItems`. What is the proper way to go around this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make `isBusy` a `var` local to the module and manipulate it directly from within your code.  Then, to expose it to the outside world, make a function that returns it-- that way other modules or constructs have access to the boolean's value for display purposes but can't manipulate its value inside your service:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .factory('appFactory', function QuestionsServ(...) {

        var service = {
            list: []
        };


        // loading state to help show if system is busy loading ajax data
        var isBusy = false;

        service.isLoading = function () {
            return isBusy;
        };


        service.loadItems = function () {
            isBusy = true;

            // make ajax call here
            var request = ...

            return request.then( function(res) {
                 // after successful loading show state is not busy
                 isBusy = false;
                 ...
            }
```

Comment: Aaaah! Okay, so the problem was simply that I was binding `isBusy` directly to the object `service`... and so it was also made public with the availability of `service`. The answer, as you highlighted, was simply to make `isBusy` local to the factory only and exclusive to the `service` object. Thanks man!

Comment: @Grateful - no problem! Happy coding!

Comment: Secondly, I presume that the result is the same whether `isBusy` is declared with `var` or not.

Comment: @Grateful - **no**, actually-- you have to be very careful with that.  JavaScript is a bit wonky with its `var` declarations.  Basically, wherever you declare using the `var` keyword you are saying that the `var` name will be local to that function scope and not above.  If you omit the `var` then it will start looking up through parent function scopes until it finds a `var` of the same name-- if none is found, it is declared globally instead.  The way I wrote it keeps it local to the service definition, and nested functions refer to it w/o `var` so they are all using the same variable.

Comment: Also, in case you're new or new-ish to JavaScript, you might want to take a peek at [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting).  It's a weird gotcha.  But if you stick to [Douglas Crockford's](http://javascript.crockford.com/) "good parts" of Javascript, you'll save yourself some headaches.  Or learn ES2015 JS, as it allows block-level scoping.  Good luck!